# What's the best way to get an object from Java Enumeration without code loops?

Tags: scala, loops, mapreduce

What's the best way to get an object from Java Enumeration using Scala? I'm retrieving this value using a while loop but i would like to use something like .map() and get this without need to code a loop:

```
private def getMsgId(mimeMessage: MimeMessage): String = {
    var msgId: String = null
    val iterator = enumerationAsScalaIterator(mimeMessage.getAllHeaders())
    breakable {
      while (iterator.hasNext) {
        val header = iterator.next.asInstanceOf[Header]
        if (header.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("MessageId")) {
          msgId = header.getValue()
          break
        }
      }
    }
    return msgId;
}
```

What's is the another options to get value "header.getValue()" without using loops like while or for?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One note: if your function might actually *not* find a message ID you're looking for, it should return `Option[String]` instead.
Having said that, there already is an implicit conversion from `Enumeration[A]` to Scala's `Iterator[A]`, you just have to:

```
import collection.JavaConversions.enumerationAsScalaIterator
```

and after that:

```
 mimeMessage.getAllHeaders
            .find(_.getName.equalsIgnoreCase("MessageId")
            .map(_.getValue)
```

which will return `Option[String]`.

Comment: I'm getting an error "value getName is not a member of ?0". Any idea how to do a 'cast' here?

Comment: @DavidL. If the enumeration is generic, the iterator should be too. If, for whatever reason, it's not the case, you should just put `.map(_.asInstanceOf[Header])` before `.find`.